# C#: Reading the next file in a folder?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a folder containing `.txt` files which are numbered like so:

```
0.txt
1.txt
...
867.txt
...
```

What I am trying to do is each time `readNextFile();` is called, I want it to return the contents of the next file in that folder, and `return string.Empty;` if there is no file after the last one it read. *I want to have a button that, when pressed, will make the program read the next file and do stuff with it's contents. The files might change between button presses.* The way I did this before was this:

```
int lastFileNumber = 0;

string readNextFile()
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    //I know it is recommended to use as few of these as possible, this is just an example.
    try
    {
        string file = Path.Combine("C:\Somewhere", lastFileNumber.ToString() + ".txt");
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            result = File.ReadAllText(file);
            lastFileNumber++;
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    return result;
}
```

Problem is there might sometimes be this kind of situation:

```
0.txt
1.txt
5.txt
6.txt
...
```

It would obviously get stuck at `1.txt` because `2.txt` doesn't exist. I need it to skip to the next existing file and read that one. And clearly it is **not possible to just sort the file names alphabetically** in a string array since the file names are not Padded, so doing that will result in `1000000000.txt` being read right after `1.txt`.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use linq to check the next file based on the stored number. That is done after ordering the file by converting its name into integer representation:

```
int lastFileNumber = -1;
bool isFirst = true;
private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int lastFileNumberLocal = isFirst ? -1 : lastFileNumber;
    isFirst = false;
    int dummy;
    var currentFile = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                            .Select(x => new { Path = x, NameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x) })
                            .Where(x => Int32.TryParse(x.NameOnly, out dummy))
                            .OrderBy(x => Int32.Parse(x.NameOnly))
                            .Where(x => Int32.Parse(x.NameOnly) > lastFileNumberLocal)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

    if (currentFile != null)
    {
        lastFileNumber = Int32.Parse(currentFile.NameOnly);

        string currentFileContent = File.ReadAllText(currentFile.Path);
    }
    else
    {
       // reached the end, do something or show message
    }
}
```

Comment: You said that no files have to be added while it's reading. problem is I want to have a button that when pressed will make the program read the next file and do stuff with it's contents.

Comment: @user152356 So where is the problem. No files are created while you're reading write ?

Comment: Edited the question: I want to have a button that, when pressed, will make the program read the next file and do stuff with it's contents. The files might change between button presses.

Comment: @user152356 Ahh ok. I'll edit the answer. But what if a missing file number gets added ?

Comment: I didn't understand... If it skips to 5.txt and after it reads it 3.txt and 4.txt appear? If that's the case then ignore it, just continue to 6.txt...

Comment: Slight problem: it started by reading 1.txt, when it should have started with 0, and it also crashes if there is nothing after 6.txt, when it should return string.empty. Otherwise it is just what I was looking for. Can you just fix these two problems?

Comment: @user152356 I already edited the answer to handle the end of the files. Also, start the `lastFileNumber` from `-1` and not `0`.

Comment: The thing is other parts of the program also need to read lastFileNumber, so it might confuse them. and i am not gonna go through all of the references and add +1.

Comment: @user152356 I think this is enough, you can solve these small problems yourself as the idea now is clear. Please mark this as the accepted answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: You should be using `EnumerateFiles`....`GetFiles` will read in all files in the directory into an array first. If the number of files gets quite large, the method will start taking an inordinate amount of time to run,even for the first file (I speak from experience where a directory of 10,000 files was impeding execution). `EnumerateFiles` will use deferred execution as it returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` (and not a `string[]`)  and likewise would also need some other minor changes to adapt for

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Useful tip, will definitely use that. Thanks.

Comment: Also the best way to sort would be to implement a custom `IComparer` that does the integer parsing. You'd pass that to `OrderBy` . This then becomes be reusable.  Though in this case you lose the last file number you are tracking

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can find what file is last without getting the whole list of files first. The sorting can be simplified by sorting by the file name length and then by the file name.

```
int currentFileNumber = -1;
string currentFileName;
string currentFileText;
string[] allFileNames;

string readCurrentFile()
{
    try
    {
        if (allFileNames == null) allFileNames = (
                from f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@".", "*.*")
                orderby f.Length, f  select f).ToArray(); 

        currentFileNumber++;

        if (currentFileNumber >= allFileNames.Length) return null; // no files left

        currentFileName = allFileNames[currentFileNumber];

        currentFileText = File.ReadAllText(currentFileName);

        return currentFileText;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return readCurrentFile(); // get next file if any Exception
    }
}
```